# Chrome extension QR code maker

Tags: gratis, chrome

I sometimes see addresses (UK) and phone numbers (UK) and links when surfing.

Is there a chrome extension that can detect what the selection is (nunber/address/link, etc...) and on right click it is converted to a QR code?

This will be useful for Android phones because they support adding contacts from QR codes.